# Mapping from Run-Time Environment Data Model to Tracking Model

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

- Activity 1
- Activity 2
- Activity 3

Suppose that the Current Activity is Activity 1. Activity 1 has a primary objective. Activity 1 sets cmi.objectives.0.success_status = passed and it never sets cmi.success_status. In this case, after mapping data from Run-Time Environment data model to Tracking Model the ObjectiveProgressStatus and ObjectiveSatisfiedStatus of the primary objective of the Activity 1 are set to False. In fact, after mapping, cmi.success_status is overwritten on cmi.objectives.0.success_status. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, not correct. The primary objective cannot be directly accessed at runtime. To set its tracking data at runtime, you have to use "cmi.success_status" or "cmi.score.scaled". One more thing, tracking data of local obectives other than the primary objective are handled by the SCO only and the role of the LMS is just to keep track of their status without taking any action based on their tracking data. The primary objective is the core of the activity and it holds its tracking data.

Comment: What information must be retrieved if a SCO calls GetValue("cmi.objectives.0.success_status")? The success_status of primary objective (<primaryObjective>) or the success_status of the first objective (<objective>)?

Comment: "cmi.objectives.0.success_status" has nothing to do with the primary objective. If you call GetValue("cmi.objectives.0.success_status"), you will get the value you have assinged to it by calling SetValue("cmi.objectives.0.success_status,"passed/failed"). If you want to get the success status of the primary objective, you have to call GetValue("cmi.success_status").

Comment: Suppost the Activity only has a primary objective in its manifest. In this case, what value must be retrieved if a SCO calls GetValue("cmi.objectives._count") for the first time?

Comment: The returned value will be "0" because the primary objective is not included in the "cmi.objectives._count". It stands on its own separated from the other objectives. Think of the primary objective as the core of the activity itself. In fact, the LMS makes many rollup and sequencing decisions based on the primary objective.